# Linux CPU soft lockup, kernel tained, system hung

Tags: linux, kernel-modules

Recently, some Linux VMs got an abruptly significant increase in CPU speed,then system hung. Sometimes, thete is no reported crash log at all.

Below is the message that show up when CPU soft lockup happened,then system hung in a short time. I am not sure what caused it, as seems kernel tained by flag G is not a problem ?

(G: the kernel has been tainted (for a reason indicated by a different flag), but all modules loaded into it were licensed under the GPL or a license compatible with the GPL.)

```
> ==================================================================== Sep 27 10:21:20 hadoop-9 kernel: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#2 stuck for
> 22s! [kworker/2:1:675] Sep 27 10:21:20 hadoop-9 kernel: Modules linked
> in: dccp_diag dccp tcp_diag udp_diag inet_diag unix_diag
> af_packet_diag netlink_diag iptable_filter fuse btrfs zlib_deflate
> raid6_pq xor vfat msdos fat ext4 mbcache jbd2 binfmt_misc bridge stp
> llc vmw_vsock_vmci_transport vsock coretemp crc32_pclmul
> ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper
> cryptd ppdev vmw_balloon pcspkr i2c_piix4 shpchp sg vmw_vmci
> parport_pc parport ip_tables xfs libcrc32c sr_mod cdrom ata_generic
> pata_acpi sd_mod crc_t10dif crct10dif_generic vmwgfx drm_kms_helper
> ttm crct10dif_pclmul crct10dif_common drm crc32c_intel serio_raw
> ata_piix vmxnet3 libata i2c_core vmw_pvscsi floppy dm_mirror
> dm_region_hash dm_log dm_mod Sep 27 10:21:20 hadoop-9 kernel: CPU: 2
> PID: 675 Comm: kworker/2:1 Tainted: G             L ------------  
> 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64 #1 Sep 27 10:21:20 hadoop-9 kernel: Hardware name: VMware, Inc. VMware Virtual Platform/440BX Desktop Reference
> Platform, BIOS 6.00 09/21/2015 Sep 27 10:21:20 hadoop-9 kernel:
> Workqueue: events_freezable vmballoon_work [vmw_balloon] Sep 27
> 10:21:20 hadoop-9 kernel: task: ffff880fe3d51700 ti: ffff88003635c000
> task.ti: ffff88003635c000 Sep 27 10:21:20 hadoop-9 kernel: RIP:
> 0010:[<ffffffff8108dbc8>]  [<ffffffff8108dbc8>]
> run_timer_softirq+0x68/0x340 Sep 27 10:21:20 hadoop-9 kernel: RSP:
> 0018:ffff880ffe643e68  EFLAGS: 00000206 Sep 27 10:21:20 hadoop-9
> kernel: RAX: 000000011481b2fc RBX: ffff880ffe654780 RCX:
> ffff880ffe643e90 Sep 27 10:21:20 hadoop-9 kernel: RDX:
> 000000011481b2fb RSI: ffff880ffe643e90 RDI: ffff880fe707c000 Sep 27
> 10:21:20 hadoop-9 kernel: RBP: ffff880ffe643ed0 R08: 0001392dd1824e00
> R09: 00000000000000ff Sep 27 10:21:20 hadoop-9 kernel: R10:
> 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000005 R12: ffff880ffe643dd8 Sep 27
> 10:21:20 hadoop-9 kernel: R13: ffffffff8164655d R14: ffff880ffe643ed0
> R15: ffff880fe707c000 Sep 27 10:21:20 hadoop-9 kernel: FS: 
> 0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff880ffe640000(0000)
> knlGS:0000000000000000 Sep 27 10:21:20 hadoop-9 kernel: CS:  0010 DS:
> 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033 Sep 27 10:21:20 hadoop-9 kernel:
> CR2: 00000000028511e6 CR3: 000000000194a000 CR4: 00000000003407e0 Sep
> 27 10:21:20 hadoop-9 kernel: DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1:
> 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000 Sep 27 10:21:20 hadoop-9
> kernel: DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000fffe0ff0 DR7:
> 0000000000000400 Sep 27 10:21:20 hadoop-9 kernel: Stack: Sep 27
> 10:21:20 hadoop-9 kernel: ffff880fe707dc28 ffff880fe707d828
> ffff880fe707d428 ffff880fe707d028 Sep 27 10:21:20 hadoop-9 kernel:
> ffff880ffe643ea8 ffff880ffe643e90 ffff880ffe643e90 000000002783652e
> Sep 27 10:21:20 hadoop-9 kernel: 0000000000000001 0000000000000001
> 0000000000000000 ffffffff81943088 Sep 27 10:21:20 hadoop-9 kernel:
> Call Trace: Sep 27 10:21:20 hadoop-9 kernel: <IRQ>  Sep 27 10:21:20
> hadoop-9 kernel:  Sep 27 10:21:20 hadoop-9 kernel:
> [<ffffffff81084b0f>] __do_softirq+0xef/0x280 Sep 27 10:21:20 hadoop-9
> kernel: [<ffffffff8164721c>] call_softirq+0x1c/0x30 Sep 27 10:21:20
> hadoop-9 kernel: [<ffffffff81016fc5>] do_softirq+0x65/0xa0 Sep 27
> 10:21:20 hadoop-9 kernel: [<ffffffff81084ea5>] irq_exit+0x115/0x120
> Sep 27 10:21:20 hadoop-9 kernel: [<ffffffff81647e95>]
> smp_apic_timer_interrupt+0x45/0x60 Sep 27 10:21:20 hadoop-9 kernel:
> [<ffffffff8164655d>] apic_timer_interrupt+0x6d/0x80 Sep 27 10:21:20
> hadoop-9 kernel: <EOI>  Sep 27 10:21:20 hadoop-9 kernel:  Sep 27
> 10:21:20 hadoop-9 kernel: [<ffffffffa02b1553>] ?
> vmballoon_work+0x2b3/0x720 [vmw_balloon] Sep 27 10:21:20 hadoop-9
> kernel: [<ffffffff8109d5fb>] process_one_work+0x17b/0x470 Sep 27
> 10:21:20 hadoop-9 kernel: [<ffffffff8109e3cb>]
> worker_thread+0x11b/0x400 Sep 27 10:21:20 hadoop-9 kernel:
> [<ffffffff8109e2b0>] ? rescuer_thread+0x400/0x400 Sep 27 10:21:20
> hadoop-9 kernel: [<ffffffff810a5aef>] kthread+0xcf/0xe0 Sep 27
> 10:21:20 hadoop-9 kernel: [<ffffffff810a5a20>] ?
> kthread_create_on_node+0x140/0x140 Sep 27 10:21:20 hadoop-9 kernel:
> [<ffffffff81645858>] ret_from_fork+0x58/0x90 Sep 27 10:21:20 hadoop-9
> kernel: [<ffffffff810a5a20>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x140/0x140 Sep
> 27 10:21:20 hadoop-9 kernel: Code: df e8 dd f0 5a 00 48 83 bb 28 20 00
> 00 00 75 3d 48 8b 05 4c 74 9e 00 48 89 43 10 0f 1f 44 00 00 66 83 03
> 02 fb 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 <48> 8b 45 d0 65 48 33 04 25 28 00 00 00 0f 85
> be 02 00 00 48 83  Sep 27 10:21:22 hadoop-9 abrt-dump-oops: Reported 1
> kernel oopses to Abrt Sep 27 10:21:33 hadoop-9 kernel:
> blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0 Sep 27 10:21:34
> hadoop-9 logger: os-prober: debug: running
> /usr/libexec/os-probes/mounted/05efi on mounted /dev/sda1
```

Answer (score 2):

The "quote" formatting instead of "code" is a mess, but here I've salvaged the part that's probably the most useful:

```
Sep 27 10:21:20 hadoop-9 kernel: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#2 stuck for 22s!
...
Sep 27 10:21:20 hadoop-9 kernel: Call Trace: 
Sep 27 10:21:20 hadoop-9 kernel: 
Sep 27 10:21:20 hadoop-9 kernel: 
Sep 27 10:21:20 hadoop-9 kernel: [] __do_softirq+0xef/0x280 
Sep 27 10:21:20 hadoop-9 kernel: [] call_softirq+0x1c/0x30 
Sep 27 10:21:20 hadoop-9 kernel: [] do_softirq+0x65/0xa0 
Sep 27 10:21:20 hadoop-9 kernel: [] irq_exit+0x115/0x120 
Sep 27 10:21:20 hadoop-9 kernel: [] smp_apic_timer_interrupt+0x45/0x60 
Sep 27 10:21:20 hadoop-9 kernel: [] apic_timer_interrupt+0x6d/0x80 
Sep 27 10:21:20 hadoop-9 kernel: 
Sep 27 10:21:20 hadoop-9 kernel: 
Sep 27 10:21:20 hadoop-9 kernel: [] ? vmballoon_work+0x2b3/0x720 [vmw_balloon] 
Sep 27 10:21:20 hadoop-9 kernel: [] process_one_work+0x17b/0x470 
Sep 27 10:21:20 hadoop-9 kernel: [] worker_thread+0x11b/0x400 
Sep 27 10:21:20 hadoop-9 kernel: [] ? rescuer_thread+0x400/0x400 
Sep 27 10:21:20 hadoop-9 kernel: [] kthread+0xcf/0xe0 
Sep 27 10:21:20 hadoop-9 kernel: [] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x140/0x140 
Sep 27 10:21:20 hadoop-9 kernel: [] ret_from_fork+0x58/0x90 
Sep 27 10:21:20 hadoop-9 kernel: [] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x140/0x140
```

The upper part of the call trace looks like a pretty generic trace of timer interrupt triggering. That's probably what has detected the soft lockup.

The bottom part seems to be that the system has been in the `vmw_balloon` driver. That driver is used with VMware, and it allows the underlying virtualization host to tell the VM that it temporarily cannot use the full amount of RAM assigned to it. If I've understood correctly, it makes a contiguous, unpageable memory allocation in the VM's operating system, and then reports its location to the virtualization host: "this part of the RAM assigned to this VM is now blocked off, you can now reuse it elsewhere".

The fact that the CPU #2 has been busy for 22 seconds in that single driver suggests to me that there might be some shortage of RAM: either the VM would need the memory that has been ballooned away and the virtualization host cannot give it back in a timely fashion, or the virtualization host needs more RAM elsewhere and is desperately trying to claim more from the VMs.

You should talk to the administrators of the virtualization host, and have them check the memory statistics of the host. It is possible to overcommit the RAM allocation (i.e. have the sum of the RAM allocations to VMs be more than the system actually has available) by some amount if it is expected that some VMs will pretty much always be idle when others are busy; but if there is too much overcommitting, it will ruin the overall performance of the system. This error might be a side effect of the virtualization host promising way too much RAM and being unable to actually deliver it.

If the statistics show the virtualization host is running out of RAM, then the quickes fix could be to migrate one or more VMs to another host with enough free RAM available. If that is not possible, then more actual physical RAM needs to be added to the host system, which may require downtime.

Comment: Thank you telcoM,  got to know the host with 192GB RAM, there are 3 VMs running which is allocated  64GB RAM per VM. I see the VM's comsumed RAM increased much before memory ballon happened,  it should be related with RAM allocation~,  However,  why did memory ballon happened without RAM overcommit？

Comment: The hypervisor running on the host will require some (hopefully small) amount of memory for its own operations too. If the host has exactly 192 GB of physical RAM and you're running 3 VMs with 64 GB of memory each, there would be nothing left for the hypervisor itself. This is impossible, so you are already overcommitting in some degree.  VMware ESXi requires an absolute minimum of 4 GB of physical RAM to boot, and the recommended minimum is 8 GB if you want to do anything useful with it... so that suggests the ESXi hypervisor would need about 4 Gb for its own use, maybe a bit more.

Comment: Got it, thank you, I'll arrange reconfigure the amount of each VM